# Combine async/await with async control flows

Tags: node.js, async-await, async.js

How to combine async/await with [async control flows](https://github.com/caolan/async)?:

```
async.parallel([
  (next) => asyncFN1,
  (next) => asyncFN2,
  (next) => {
    Model.find(filter).exec( async(err, result) => {
      if (await asyncFn3()){
        return next("Some err")
      }
      return next(null, result)
    })

  } 
], callback)
```

1) Is it Ok to do the control flow with async/await and the callback combined?

2) Do I need to handle the Promise async/await returns?

3) Can async be directly on the control flow fn e.g.

```
async.parallel([
  (next) => asyncFN1,
  async (next) => {
    const result = await asyncFN4()
    return next(null, result)
  }
```

Comment: If you need parallel execution, then `Promise.all` might also be a good fit instead of importing a whole library. And promise.all is also much simpler to reason about.

Comment: Its mainly I use the async library in the project, but I don't want to nest it any deeper. This would handling async if/else blocks easier for me.